# Multi user resume manager in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, user

I need a multi user resume website in joomla , where anyone can create a unique login and prepare  resume (similar to one page website). Is there any template/extension available for this ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you have showed no research effort at all. Try here http://extensions.joomla.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different ways:

- Try with some [Job Board](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/ads-a-affiliates/jobs-a-recruitment) extension.
- Try with some [CCK](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-construction) extension.
- Build your custom solution with [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) or [Component Creator](https://www.component-creator.com).